# Mapear base de datos con Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

tengo que realizar un proyecto web en php y conozco aspectos generales de Laravel, por lo que me gustaría utilizarlo en el desarrollo, lo que me detiene por el momento es mapear la base de datos que tengo creada en mysql con laravel, es posible hacer esto? estuve buscando en internet pero no encuentro nada concreto, si pudieran ayudarme con alguna guía o documento.

Gracias de antemano..

Saludos_!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar [Eloquent Model Generator](https://github.com/krlove/eloquent-model-generator)

Una vez añadida la herramienta a laravel, podes correr lo siguiente para ir creando los modelos:

Suponiendo que tenes una tabla que se llama usuarios

```
php artisan krlove:generate:model Usuario --table-name=usuarios
```

Y eso te generaría la clase Usuario con sus relaciones, siempre y cuando estén seteadas las foreign keys, para que pueda darse cuenta.

Como alternativa existe otra herramienta llamada [Reliese Laravel](https://github.com/reliese/laravel) que te arma todos los modelos en un solo comando, pero nunca la he usado.

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias crack! se presentó un problema por el tipo BIT pero lo cambie a Boolean y siguió sin dramas ;)

Answer (score 1):

Si ya tienes definida la base de datos y quieres utilizar esas tablas como modelos en Laravel simplemente configura tu proyecto para que utilice la base de datos que deseas, para hacer esto modifica los valores en tus variables de entorno:

**/.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mibasededatos
DB_USERNAME=el_usuario_de_tu_db
DB_PASSWORD=la_clave_de_tu_usuario
```

Luego, crea tus modelos según las tablas de tu base de datos:

```
php artisan make:model Employee
```

y por último configura cada modelo para que se conecte a la tabla correcta:

**app/Employee.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model {

    // con lo siguiente configuras la tabla que utilizará el modelo
    protected $table = 'employees';

    // y con esto especificas el nombre de la llave primaria de la tabla
    protected $primaryKey = 'employee_id';

    // el resto del código.. por ejemplo relaciones con otros modelos
}
```